# why does the PayPal in context express checkout flow break with during a HKD checkout?

Tags: paypal

I'm attempting to conduct financial transactions with the paypal api using what their documentation describes as 'in context, express checkout'.  I have everything working properly when I use USD as the checkout currency but I'm having trouble using HKD and I will outline my situation below.

Given a normal in context express checkout flow of

1. get express checkout token
2. give user a link that paypal checkout.js detects the click of
3. user authrorizes the in context transaction
4. paypal post the token/payer_id back to my server

**USD FLOW - everything ok**

get express checkout token,

POST TO PAY PAL

`"USER=hidden-facilitator_api1.gmail.com&PWD=NWhidden3TK&SIGNATURE=Arhidden3tCjMfqZyNAlfdDvZ6YAyktOYxObIAzKBgV0N2&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=109.0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=2000.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&RETURNURL=http://localhost:3000/checkout/complete?cartId=126&CANCELURL=http://localhost:3000/checkout/cancel&LANDING=Billing&ADDROVERRIDE=0&NOSHIPPING=1"`

Returns Express checkout token

`EC-8GN42843W29871826`

Which I then embed in the browser as

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?useraction=commit&token=EC-8GN42843W29871826&ul=0`

Which works fine, initiating the in context checkout flow as referenced here, 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbigq78achl0xsy/Screenshot%202015-08-05%2011.43.12.png?dl=0

**HKD FLOW - everything BROKEN**

GET express checkout token

POST TO PAY PAL

`"USER=hidden-facilitator_api1.gmail.com&PWD=NWXhiddenTK&SIGNATURE=ArOphiddenzfdDvZ6YAyktOYxObIAzKBgV0N2&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=109.0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=2000.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=HKD&RETURNURL=http://localhost:3000/checkout/complete?cartId=126&CANCELURL=http://localhost:3000/checkout/cancel&LANDING=Billing&ADDROVERRIDE=0&NOSHIPPING=1"`

Returns Express Checkout Token

`EC-4JK68416ST774680H`

Which is embedded as get in the browser as

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?useraction=commit&token=EC-4JK68416ST774680H&ul=0`

Which when clicked actually totally hijacks and pretty much breaks the checkout process, the in context browser 'modal' opens but then something bad happens, the browser modal window closes itself and the parent browser context appears to be in some kind of redirect loop.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2snlujy8mtljwv/Screenshot%202015-08-05%2011.47.18.png?dl=0

I've contacted PayPal merchant/technical support crew and their answers were so bad it was almost like they either weren't reading my email, didn't care about my problem or just generally were incompetent and I hesitate to criticize someone professionally, but if paypal is taking a cut of transactions, I expect the supporting api and documentation to not be terrible.

What can I do in this situation to gain further insight into the problem that I'm having ?

Cheers and thanks,

JD

UPDATES:

The process is failing specifically related to HKD when I attempt to launch the in context browser window with `paypal.checkout` and I can successfully complete this process with other foreign currencies including (but not limited to) `'PLN'` (polish zloty), `'DKK'` (danish krone) but fails for `'HKD'` (hong kong dollar) and `'THB'` (thai baht), so maybe paypal checkout.js doesn't like certain regions ?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the devil was in the details but PayPal express checkout and pay pal checkout support `HKD` but in context checkout using checkout.js does not support this and my troubles were tied to erroneously believing the the false parts.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7s0i5g0y718c8r/Screenshot%202015-08-05%2013.44.27.png?dl=0

Comment: I have been having problems with Israel and Japan - it reverts to the classic journey for those countries.